# Python and threading: Why is extracting the computation outside of the locked area speeding up the code?

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, sha256, hashlib

I am preparing a session for my team on threading and locking in Python and I've run into a situation I don't fully understand.

In the code below, I'm computing hashes of many (1000) large strings (100k+ chars) using Thread pool in Python (pool of 20). The hashes are then stored in the dictionary `digest`, and so I use locking when writing to the dictionary (I think that may not actually be necessary - but let's suppose it is and we need to lock).

The version A) does the expensive hash computation within the lock statement, version B) does it before acquiring the lock, and then only updates the dictionary with the result in the critical section.

```py
import threading
import time
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import hashlib

# A) computation is within the lock statement
lock = threading.Lock()

digests = {}

def compute_digests(x):
  s = '*'*(x + 100000)  # generate some big string
  
  with lock:
    digests[x] = hashlib.sha256(f'{s}'.encode()).hexdigest()

tic = time.time()
ThreadPool(20).map(compute_digests, range(1000))
toc = time.time()
print(f'Computation in locked area: {toc - tic}s')



# B) computation is outside of the lock statement
lock = threading.Lock()

digests = {}

def compute_digests(x):
  s = '*'*(x + 100000)  # generate some big string
  digest = hashlib.sha256(f'{s}'.encode()).hexdigest()
  
  with lock:
    digests[x] = digest

tic = time.time()
ThreadPool(20).map(compute_digests, range(1000))
toc = time.time()
print(f'Computation outside of locked area: {toc - tic}s')
```

The results are:

```
Computation in locked area: 0.41937875747680664s
Computation outside of locked area: 0.10702204704284668s
```

In other words, option B) is faster. That may seem intuitive given that we moved the expensive computation outside of the locked block of code, however, based on what I read, Python is **single threaded anyway** and the `ThreadPool` only gives ***appearance*** of doing work in parallel - whereas in reality only one computation runs at any moment. In other words, I would expect the Global Interpreter Lock to be the bottleneck, but somehow, there is a substantial speedup with version B)!

So the question is, where is that speedup coming from? Is that something to do with the implementation of sha256 (that perhaps sleeps somewhere)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is not single threaded. It uses normal system threads as any C++ or Java code would. The difference is the [global interpreter lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) (GIL) which can be released by inner C code such as hashlib, while running pure Python code forces a single thread to execute at a time.

In this case, the interpreter would be free to run different code but you forced it not to with the lock.

Comment: Ah thanks, I think I understand. So in option B), several threads of the pool can dive into the C code for Hashlib at the same time because that code does not require GIL to be locked? I thought that all Python instructions, including those triggering the C code, would require GIL to be locked throughout the execution of the underlying C code. But thinking about it, that would have been a waste of time as the pure Python could do other things meanwhile. (Is this thinking roughly correct?)

Comment: Any C code can **choose** to release the GIL if they know they are safe and things will parallelize well. It is usual when doing CPU bound tasks to use multiple processes instead of threads and leave this for I/O bound tasks which for sure will release the GIL waiting on data. Check the multiprocessing library

Comment: @Ferrard Imagine C code that implements I/O. If it couldn't release the GIL, the threading wouldn't work at all as a single python thread blocking on I/O would stop the whole program.